# How to connect a signal from an object created by stackview.push in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have an object in QML that will be created using the `.push` function of stackview like so:

```
stackview.push(myObject)
```

and I would like to connect to a signal from myObject. Inside the object I have a signal.

This is how I connected it:

```
myObject.onMySignal.connect(function (){
    console.log("Signal Recieved")
})
```

The problem is I am not receiving the signal. So I concluded that I have done it incorrectly. Please help.

Below is the part of the code where I have done my solution:

```
StackView {
    width: parent.width

    id: stackView
    initialItem:HomeForm{height: root.height-toolbar.height ; width: root.width}
    anchors.fill: parent

    Component.onCompleted: {

        initialItem.onSubjectClicked.connect(function(index){
             stackView.push("qrc:/AttendanceList.qml")
             AttendanceList.onSessionItemClicked.connect(function (data){
                console.log("Attendance click registered with index: " + data)
             })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: hello sir i edited it to contain the part where it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QML,   `connect()` is a signal *method*, so you use it as such; either to connect `signal` to a `function` or signal to signal.

You are using the signal *handler* in the `connect()` and that's absolutely wrong:

```
myObject.onMySignal.connect(function (){})    // Wrong
```

You must use the signal name not handler in `connect()`

```
myObject.mySignal.connect(function (){})    // Correct signal to function
```

So, you can use it for signal to signal like this:

```
AttendanceList.sessionItemClicked.connect(mySignal)
```

or signal to function like:

```
AttendanceList.sessionItemClicked.connect(function(){ ...})
```

In the second form its signal to signal connect .. do not use a function.

[Connecting Signals to Methods and Signals](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmlevents.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals)

Answer (score 0):

Well, to access the the pushed element you have to use `currentItem` as a reference. Please note to care about the points from @Mohammad Kanan, too.

```
StackView {
    width: parent.width

    id: stackView
    initialItem:HomeForm{height: root.height-toolbar.height ; width: root.width}
    anchors.fill: parent

    Component.onCompleted: {

        initialItem.subjectClicked.connect(function(index){
             stackView.push("qrc:/AttendanceList.qml")
             stackView.currentItem.sessionItemClicked.connect(function (data){
                console.log("Attendance click registered with index: " + data)
             })
        })
    }
}
```